# Split values in a dropdown list and display on a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, excel-2010

I have a excell sheet with a drop down list. The values are some comma separated values. For example

```
XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL
2/3, 4/5, 6/7, 8/9, 10/11, 12/13
1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12, 12-13, 13-14, 14-15, 15-16, 18-24
2XL, 3XL, 4XL, 5XL
1X, 2X, 3X, 4X, 5X
```

When user selects a value from the drop down I want to get the selected value and split it by comma and set those splited values to cells.
If User selects 2XL, 3XL, 4XL, 5XL my output should look as follows.Can anybody suggests a better to do this

[image]

Comment: Data->Text to Columns ?

Comment: in which cell is your validation list? do you want to overwrite this cell? where do you want to place new values in reference to validation cell?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up your spreadsheet like this

[image]

Cell `C2` is the validation list dropdown

turn on the developer tab and go into VBE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

right click the `Sheet1` object module and select `View Code`

copy paste the below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 3 Then
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(Target, ",")
        Range("E:E").ClearContents
        Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
        Range("E1:E" & UBound(arr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, go back to spreadsheet and select anything in the list. You should have your separated values in column `E`

[image]

Comment: What I want is add those to column wise not row wise.I changed the range to the column and did the another Transpose
WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr))
Thanks for your clear answer

Comment: @udaya726 oh yeah sorry i missed that but yeah you took the right approach. You could have edited the `Range("E1:E" & UBound(arr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)` changing range to cells like `cells(1, 5 + ubound(arr)) = arr` i think it would work i havent tested but something similar

Comment: Hi Now I am facing a small issue which I couldnt figure.I add this to excel file and save it as a .xlsm.Its really works in my machine but not in any other though the macros enabled. The vesions and the platform also same.Any idea about it